# How to use index for VARCHAR field in MySQL with LIKE and partial match?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, database-indexes

I have a MySQL table with 42 million records in it.
"name" field in this table has index on it (NOT UNIQUE and NOT PK)

If I use

```
SELECT x FROM table WHERE name='asdef'
```

it uses index and I get the result quickly.

IF I use

```
SELECT x FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%sd%'
```

it does not use index even if I use `FORCE INDEX` or `USE INDEX`.

I am absolutely in need of doing partial matching. How can I do this while keeping my field as VARCHAR?

Comment: What would the DB do with the index in this case?  Your match starts with a wildcard, and therefore order doesn't matter.  It must look at every name value for a match.  Assuming 'x' is something more than 'name', the DB might as well go through the table rows.  If your match pattern is constant and you need to do this lookup frequently, perhaps you can check this condition on insert and have a separate column (e.g. "has_sd") and index that so you can have a fast lookup.

Comment: @sbaker I cannot check it as the `name` I search cannot be guessed and it is dynamically defined by user.

Comment: MySQL (unlike Postgres) can not use an index for `LIKE '%sd%'`. Look into the built-in full text search.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have a problem.  And, SQL may provide some tools, but they may not solve your problem.

First, is your "partial" search really for a word inside a phrase.  If so, you can use MySQL full text search to look for words.  You may need to pay attention to the stop word list and minimum search length to make it work for your data.

Second, are the names repeated throughout the table?  If so, then normalization will help.  For instance, if there are 50 thousand names for the 42 million records, searching through the 50 thousand is much more feasible.

Third, are there a handful of finite terms that you are looking for?  If so, then you can add flags into the table that are maintained via triggers.

Fourth, how wide are the rows, independent of `name`?  If the rows are wide, you can make the exhaustive search more efficient by storing `name` in a separate table that fits and stays in memory.